# Make an http Server - Recommended books?

Tags: c, http

I am interested in making a simple HTTP server in C to play with (of course I'm only expecting to learn more about how a server works and gain some knowledge from there). I saw some topics regarding the same question as well as providing code but that didnt help. Are there any books for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Why are you asking? What do you already know? What did you try? What code did you study or improve?

Comment: I completed my answer below: HTTP is complex, and you won't be able to *fully implement* it in a *simple* program. The toy HTTP implementations of less than a thousand line implement incompletely a subset of HTTP specification (think about it, the HTTP spec is a hundred of pages, how could it be fully implemented by a tiny program)!

Comment: Actually, I am old enough (and lucky enough) to have written my first programs in PL/1 on punched cards on an IBM 370/168 (in 1974, I was a teenager then). At that time, the Internet did not exist, and I had to read many things (heavy reference manuals) and ask in person to many people (my father was an R&D engineer, then at IBM France, and had to proof-read a book on PL/1 by M.Dornbush).

Answer (score 4):

First, there are many HTTP server C code out there. At least, have a look into some of them.

There are also several libraries for adding HTTP server abilities to your software. I do like the [onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) library, but there are others ([libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/), [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) for C++, etc...).

You need to be fluent with

- [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/)
- [unix networking programming](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html)
- [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/HTTP_Protocol)
- [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html)
- [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) perhaps

I'm not sure it is worth the effort to re-implement a simple HTTP server. You probably won't do better than existing stuff in a reasonable time.

You might learn more by studying and improving existing code.

At last, your question is perhaps off-topic here. Did you consider asking on [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)'s forum?

Actually, since HTTP is a complex protocol (above TCP/IP which is itself complex, implemented e.g. on operating systems like Posix or Linux which are complex), you won't be able to make a simple but standard compliant implementation (if you want it robust enough, which is required by HTTP specs). It has to be complex!

You definitely will learn a lot by implementing something simple. Just read a little bit about HTTP (e.g. [wikipedia's page on HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), and start implementing *some simple* `GET` and `HEAD` requests); but you should have some knowledge about e.g. basic Linux network programming. However, you'll then implement only a subset of HTTP.

Comment: thanks for your answer,looks like a long long long way.I saw that thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409087/creating-a-web-server-in-pure-c and there are some code examples of about 100-200 lines that make a basic http web server.So how can i understand how these 100 lines are made and experiment with a personal attempt without having to be THAT fluent with the points you mentioned?or maybe are there any books that show some guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read this book yet but I just added it to my list. The book I am talking about is [Sockets and Pipes](https://leanpub.com/sockets-and-pipes/). However it's also a book about Haskell. So if you are interested in learning how to use Haskell to build something (instead of just learning the language) and on top of that build an HTTP server from scratch, I think this book may be helpful.